# Email has no content on some clients

Tags: php, email

It appears my email is rendered correctly only on GMail. I looked into the final headers and I don't see anything broken there:

```
From: VENE - noreply <krabuz22@gmail.com>
X-Google-Original-From: VENE - noreply <steve.steve@company.com>
Date: Fri, 31 Mar 2017 09:59:00 +0200
To: steve2@gmail.com
Subject: [VENE-LOCAL] Please verify your email
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=_xf76c2f45c241585f23339503d742de8112b91cfbx

--_xf76c2f45c241585f23339503d742de8112b91cfbx
Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

[...here goes the plain text...]

--_xf76c2f45c241585f23339503d742de8112b91cfbx
Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        [...css...]
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    [...here goes the html...]
</body>
</html>

--_xf76c2f45c241585f23339503d742de8112b91cfbx
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="file.pdf";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64;
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf";


--_xf76c2f45c241585f23339503d742de8112b91cfbx--
```

I tried removing attachment, images, changing content-types, but the result remains the same:

iPad (preview by inboxinspector.com):
[image: iPad]

This is how I combine the email:

```
protected function _sendEmail($bodyPlain, $bodyHtml, $subject, $recipients, $attachmentPath = null, $saveEmail = true) {
        if (!$bodyPlain && !$bodyHtml) {
            return false;
        }

        $boundary = '_x'.sha1(time()).'x';
        $subject = '['.$this->_config->APP_NAME.'] '.$subject;

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= 'From: '.$this->_config->EMAIL['name-noreply'].' <'.$this->_config->EMAIL['address-noreply'].'>'."\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"\n";

        $message = "";

        // Plain text body
        if (isset($bodyPlain)) {
            $message .= "\n\n--".$boundary."\n";
            $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
            $message .= $bodyPlain;
        }

        // Html body
        if (isset($bodyHtml)) {
            $message .= "\n\n--".$boundary."\n";
            $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
            $message .= $bodyHtml;
        }

        if (isset($attachmentPath)) {
            $message .= $this->_addAttachment($attachmentPath, $boundary);
        }

        $message .= "\n\n--".$boundary."--";

        foreach ($recipients as $address) {
            mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's 2017 and people still build multipart message structure by hand and use `mail()`....

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Since email-clients are still sitting around in 2000, this sort of makes sense - but feel free to suggest better options.

to the OP: have you tried sending it without the boundaries, and tried ONLY using plaintext or HTML, just to see if you then receive the content?

Comment: And what prevents you both to google for solution, **knowing** now it exists?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie yea it is received, there must be sth with these boundaries - when I pass empty HTML template it is displayed as raw text beginning with boundary